# IE11 dosen't show CSS-Content properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with content from CSS on IE11.

`.icon-ok:before{content:"\f113"}`

IE11 is computing this to `.icon-ok::before{content: normal}`
I can see that there is `.icon-ok::before{content: "\f113"}` but it is crossed.
So I didn't get the right icons there. - Ofc it is working on all other browsers.

I thought that's because of the `::before` pseudo-class, but it is computed by IE, in the source css file it is written as `:before`.

Can somebody tell me whats wrong there?

Edit:
I figured out that the IE is changing the icon-font id's.
When I use `"\f118"` in IE it is working properly there.

How can it be?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: U+F113 doesn't look like anything on my machine, but if I change it to a displayable character like U+263A, it does show in IE11, as it does in all browsers. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vk0vrL3u/). However, the odd thing is that in the inspector, the `content: \263A` bit is indeed crossed out.

Comment: I figured out that the IE is changing the icon-font id's. If I use `"f\118" it is showing the correct icon .... how the hell?

Comment: Did you really mean to say `f\118`, or was that a typo

Comment: Typo, as you can see in my post i meant `"\f118"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can happen because different browsers needs different formats of the font.
So this isn't basically a CSS problem rather a problem which format of the font is used.